# Syntax Error: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled in react js

Tags: reactjs, plugins, babeljs, jsx, preset

i am trying run my react application using npm start commamnd and installed both @babel/preset-react and @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx. but i am running this react application getting following error.

Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (7:9):

```
   6 | const PostCodeLookup = props => {
>  7 |  return <PostcodeLookup {...props} />
     |         ^
   8 |
   9 | };
```

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell with no knowledge on how you bootstrapped your app, as jaybhatt said before.

If you used react-create-app probably you messed with packages and ended up in a inconsistent state. Try to reset your app. Creating a app on another folder and migrating your code there is an option (I did that a couple of times :) !).

If you created the app structure "by hand", check if you have "@babel/preset-react" set also on webpack config:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: { presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/preset-react'] },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

- Can you tell where you bootstrapped your application from? (Create React App or something like that?)
- Also, you need to have a `.babelrc` or `babel.config.js(on)` file with these contents, just installing the packages won't work.

Putting an example below for how your `babel.config.json` should look like. Please remove any extra plugins from below example in case you use it.

```js
{
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "modules": false,
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            {
              "spec": true
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        {
          "spec": true
        }
      ],
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: i created babel.config.js file  and added above contents but facing same issues.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about where you cloned or bootstrapped your project from? Also, I hope you exported default from the `babel.config.js` file you created.